# Handling collisions in the hashmap for the specific use case enlisted below

Tags: java, collision-detection

I've written a java based web application, simple for now since I'm a beginner in this space. What it does is looks up the phone number of a person, when the user enters the name of the person in the jsp page. I'm using a hashmap for now where I've created two objects the person and the number and basically the map is the association of the person to the number. The reason I have person as an object is later on I plan to add more information to the person object. I also plan to eventually move the association to the database. **However, in this specific situation where I have a hash map how do I handle the use case of a "person with the same name" can be two different users because according to my hashmap the key is the person object. Specifically, the user can look up the person by name.** I also thought of adding a system generated id to the person object to make it unique but it doesn't solve the use case of two people having the same name as when the user is querying for the phone number he will only enter the person's name.

Comment: This isn't a problem with hash maps or whatever, this is a problem of "you don't have enough data to narrow down an individual phone number."

Comment: What kind of behavior do you want? If you search for a "name", do you intend to return 3 phone numbers?

Comment: @JonLin Yes, I'd like to return the 3 numbers but would I have to iterate over the entire hashMap for it. Is there an alternative to handling this collision ?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution would be to have your value type be a list of people, so:

```
Map<String, List<Person>> map = new HashMap...
```

It sounds like your design could do with a bit of work though.  While you're prototyping (pre database), for example, is there any reason you need to use a HashMap?  Why not just store a `List<Person>`, and iterate the list each time you want to search?  That would let you easily search on other properties of a person too.

**Edit:** In response to Phoenix's comment.

The approach is to store a list of all people with the given name in lists within the map.

To add a new person, you need to check if a person already exists with their name, and create an empty list to put them into if there isn't already a person.  [Sorry, I don't have a compiler handy, so haven't compiled or tested this, but the idea should be right]

```
void add(Map<String, List<Person>> map, Person p) {

    if (!map.containsKey(p.name()) {
        map.put(p.name(), new ArrayList<Person>());
    } 
    // The map will always have a (possibly empty) list of people with a given name now
    map.get(p.name()).add(p);
}
```

Looking people up is easy.  To print all the people with a given name:

```
void printPeople(BufferedWriter out, Map<String, List<Person>> map, String name) {
    for (Person p : map.get(name)) {
        out.println(p.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: but look up will be faster if i stored it in a hashmap, for a list i'll have to iterate over all the values

Comment: @Phoenix:  Consider 1,000 people with collisions on the the key (we'll say it's a last name) once every 125 entries.  There will be a grand total of 8 extra `Person` objects you have to iterate over to find a specific person - and there's not much of a likelihood of them all landing in the same key (think 1000 choose 125).  Iterating over the list will not be a major problem.

Comment: People with the same full name are rare enough that that's really a preferable option to iterating over the full map.

Comment: @Phoenix: I'd strongly recommend doing some performance testing.  A person object will likely have a reasonable amount of other data, which will need to be considered in the hashCode().  If you get your hashCode function wrong (they're surprisingly hard to get right), HashMap will probably be slow as hell anyway.  Simpler code is *much, much, much* easier to maintain.

Comment: Just to clarify, this solution *is* a HashMap solution.  The Lists are only used to hold people who would share a name.

Comment: @Martin I'd have to strongly disagree that `HashMap` will be slow... can you elaborate on what you really meant?

Comment: I'm not suggesting the HashMap solution is always slower - just that the difference is unlikely to be significant.  If Person.hashCode touches significant amounts of data, and there's only a handful of records, then the List solution will be faster, as it doesn't need to generate the hashes.  If the hashCode is badly written, then asymptotic performance will approach that of a List.  It sounds like the poster is doing some prototyping, and planning on implementing on a DB backend in the future.  If this is just proof of concept, then performance is unlikely to be an issue anyway.

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
Map<String, List<Person>> map = new HashMap<String, List<Person>>();

if(!map.contains(personName)){
    map.put(personName, new ArrayList<Person>());
}

// Construct Person person = new Person(personName, phoneNumber);

map.get(personName).add(person);
```

You keep a list of person as Martin suggested and put the values as list of person instead of single person.

While iterating...

```
for(Person person : map.get(personName)){
    // Process person.getPhoneNumber();
}
```

Comment: +1, beat me to the implementation (I swear I didn't copy you :)).

Comment: Thanks... Two people going in the same direction means this is the way to go :)

Comment: I disagree, because I wouldn't do what I suggested in my answer :P.  I've added a new answer with the approach I'd really take.

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding a second answer here.  My other answer shows how to implement it with a `Map`, but I don't think it's worth the effort.

If you're using a `HashMap` because you're worried about performance, then you'll fix that once you put the database backend in that you've mentioned.  As a general rule, don't spend effort optimising code you know you're going to throw away anyway, or don't know for sure even needs optimising.

My solution (pending the real backend), would be to just use a List.  You don't need to worry about getting your `hashCode` algorithm right, and I doubt it's going to come out significantly slower unless you have many thousands of entries.

```
public class People {
    private List<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();

    public void add(Person p) {
        people.add(p);
    }

    public List<Person> findByName(String name) {
        List<Person> result = new ArrayList<Person>();
        for (Person p : people) {
            if (p.getName().equals(name)) {
                result.add(p);
            }
         }
         return result;
     }
```

It's just so much simpler and clearer than the `Map` solution.

Comment: Why the -1?  Poster said they're putting in a database backend - why put effort into making the thing fast (and less clear), when the performance difference is likely to be imperceptible?